# Entity Framework Core: How to combine 2 COUNT queries into one

Tags: c#, sql, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm working on improving back-end performance with Entity Framework Core. This is a small and simple example to illustrate what I want to return:

```
var filteredMovies = _dataService
    .Repository
    .Where(movie => movie.Genre == 'Drama')
    .Where(...many other conditions, joins, etc...);

var counts1 = filteredMovies.Count(movie => movie.director == 'Spielberg');
var counts2 = filteredMovies.Count(movie => movie.director == 'Nolan');

return new Summary 
{
    SpielbergCount = counts1,
    NolanCount = counts2,
};
```

This will generate 2 SQL queries, that each go through all the WHERE, JOIN steps.
What I've seen, in SQL, is that I could write it this way to only execute 1 query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN Director = 'Spielberg' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) SpielbergCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Director = 'Nolan' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NolanCount
FROM Movies
JOIN ....
WHERE ....
```

**2 questions:**

1. How can I translate this last query into EntityFramework, to prevent executing 2 different SQL queries?
2. Is it going to improve performance? (ie: This is a small example, but I have many queries to improve, some of them very big, with most of the query being the same, except for one condition, like the Director in this example) Or is it not actually improving anything?

Thank you

Comment: Basically you have to do a `GroupBy` where you group on a constant value so that you can do the different sums in your `Select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do multiple top level aggregates in a select you have to do a group by on a constant value.

```
var counts = _dataService
    .Repository
    .Where(movie => movie.Genre == 'Drama')
    .Where(...many other conditions, joins, etc...)
    .GroupBy(x => 1)
    .Select(grp => new Summary 
    {
        SpielbergCount = grp.Count(movie => movie.director == 'Spielberg'),
        NolanCount = grp.Count(movie => movie.director == 'Nolan'),
    })
    .Single();
```

Comment: Hey juharr, you can see the reply  in @SupriyoDas 's post since you both had a very similar solution! Thanks

Comment: @NicolasDontigny Note that by grouping on a constant value the resulting select will have exactly one row and you can do a `Single` if you want.  As far as performance goes it really depends on how your table is setup, but this will get it down to one query instead of 2 which usually is more performant.

Answer (score 1):

```
return _dataService
  .Repository
  .Where(movie => movie.Genre == 'Drama')
  .Where(movie => movie.director == 'Spielberg' || movie.director == 'Nolan')
  .Where(...many other conditions, joins, etc...)
  .GroupBy(movie => movie.director)
  .Select(g => new Summary 
  {
      SpielbergCount = g.Count(x => x.director == 'Spielberg'),
      NolanCount = g.Count(x => x.director == 'Nolan'),
  });
```

**1. How can I translate this last query into EntityFramework, to prevent executing 2 different SQL queries?**

Try using Group By and Count with Filter.

**2. Is it going to improve performance?  Or is it not actually improving anything?**

Few tips to improve performance

- Avoid fetching all the fields if not required
- Retrieve only required number of records
- If you want to moves processing from the SQL server to your application server then try using AsEnumerable.

Comment: But contrary to the SUM in SQL, from my understanding, this will return a list of Summary objects because of the GroupBy.
The SQL query equivalent would be SELECT TOP(1) COUNT(...), COUNT(...) instead of just SELECT COUNT(...), COUNT(...)
So, I will have to apply .FirstOrDefault() on that object before getting the 2 counts, which doesn't seem like the best practice, what do you think?
Am I even improving performance by applying that?

Comment: This would result in 2 rows where the Spielberg row would have the correct SpeilbergCount and NolanCount would be 0 and the Nolan row would have the correct NolanCount and SpeilbergCount would be 0.  That's why you need to group on a constant value instead.